# Get sum of some rows of a pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe look like below, and I would like to calculate sum of some rows. I want to calculate this way:

I want to get the sum of rows in column 1 from "Glass" to "Tables" and then the sum of rows in column1 from "Tables" to something else, because glass to table is one category and there are other categories.

Because I have several of these sheets and for each one I don't know how many items are under each category, so I cannot sum rows by calling row index.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
                          0             1
0                     Glass       26,990 
1                   Fabrics       30,853 
2   Furniture & Accessories       136,022 
3                    Tables       132,454
4     Cabinet/Door Hardware       4,872
6                    Fences       5,952
7               Glass Doors       12,571
```

Comment: So now we know `Glass` and `Tables` belong to the same category. What about others? how do we define categories? a list of list? we don't know what you don't tell us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pd.concat()` assuming your categories are defined in a similar manner:

```
categories = [('Glass','Tables'), ('Tables','Glass Doors')]

pd.concat([df.set_index(0)[c[0]:c[1]].sum() for c in categories], keys=categories)
```

Returns:

```
Glass   Tables       1    326319
Tables  Glass Doors  1    155849
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the order is already correct:

```
df.set_index(0)['Glass':'Tables'].sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you might do

```
import pandas as pd 
categories = {'Glass': 'Category 1', 'Fabrics': 'Category 1', 
              'Furniture & Accessories': 'Category 1', 
              'Tables': 'Category 2', 'Cabinet/Door Hardware': 'Category 2',
              'Fences': 'Category 3', 'Glass Doors': 'Category 4'}
df = pd.read_csv('rfile1.csv', converters={0: lambda x: categories[x]})
df
            0       1
0  Category 1   26990
1  Category 1   30853
2  Category 1  136022
3  Category 2  132454
4  Category 2    4872
5  Category 3    5952
6  Category 4   12571

df.groupby('0').sum()
                 sum
0
Category 1  193865
Category 2  137326
Category 3    5952
Category 4   12571
```